# C - Concatenate 2 arrays in one using for loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to run a For Loop in C language to concatenate and then copy the results in a new array.

```
    // Simple array with numbers to be appended at the end of the array "type" below

char numbers[20][2]={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19"};

//after each of these words i want to append the number found above.

char type[10][30]={"rizi","makaronia","kafes","giaourti","feta","avga","sampuan","rouxa","aporipantiko","aposmitiko"};

//This is the array i wish to add the results. This way i will create 20 of each type

char random_type [20][30];

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; i < 20; j++)
        {
            strcpy(random_type[i][j],type[j]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: "10" will not fit in a `char[2]` array because of the terminating zero byte.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the expected values of the elements of `random_type` are.

Comment: infinite loop -> `for (j = 0; i < 20; j++)`, and also what is `random_type[i][j]`?

Comment: @Jasper i have set char numbers[20][2] and i have seen it fits likes this. isn't it?

Comment: A string of length 2 will need a char array of size 3 to contain it, and its terminator.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Strings the very first sentence :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simplifications can be made, such as not needing an array of consecutive numbers. There are some mistakes, such as @iharob and @Jasper pointed out, and OP used `strcpy()` to write to every char of a 2-dimensional char array, which really is a 1-D string array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define WORDS   10
#define ANSWERS 20
#define NUMBERS 20

int main()
{
    // Words to have a number appended
    char type[WORDS][30]={"rizi","makaronia","kafes","giaourti","feta",
                       "avga","sampuan","rouxa","aporipantiko","aposmitiko"};
    //This is the array to create the results.
    char random_type [ANSWERS][35];
    int i, word, numb;
    srand ((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<ANSWERS; i++) {
        numb = rand() % NUMBERS;
        word = rand() % WORDS;
        sprintf(random_type[i], "%s %d", type[word], numb);
    }
    for(i=0; i<ANSWERS; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n", random_type[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
aporipantiko 19
makaronia 14
makaronia 9
aposmitiko 10
sampuan 6
feta 10
feta 2
giaourti 3
rizi 10
feta 8
sampuan 7
rouxa 4
rizi 8
giaourti 0
giaourti 19
aposmitiko 13
rouxa 2
avga 13
giaourti 13
aporipantiko 8
```

Although, perhaps OP meant to permute every word with every number, in which case I offer this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDS   10
#define NUMBERS 20

int main()
{
    // Words to have a number appended
    char type[WORDS][30]={"rizi","makaronia","kafes","giaourti","feta",
                       "avga","sampuan","rouxa","aporipantiko","aposmitiko"};
    //This is the array to create the results.
    char random_type [WORDS][NUMBERS][35];
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<WORDS; i++)
        for(j=0; j<NUMBERS; j++)
            sprintf(random_type[i][j], "%s %d", type[i], j);
    for(i=0; i<WORDS; i++)
        for(j=0; j<NUMBERS; j++)
            printf ("%s\n", random_type[i][j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Following OP comments, yet a third solution creating one array of 600 strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDS   10
#define NUMBERS 20

int main()
{
    // Words to have a number appended
    char type[WORDS][30]={"rizi","makaronia","kafes","giaourti","feta",
                       "avga","sampuan","rouxa","aporipantiko","aposmitiko"};
    //This is the array to create the results.
    char random_type [WORDS*NUMBERS][35];
    int i, j, k=0;
    for(i=0; i<WORDS; i++)
        for(j=0; j<NUMBERS; j++)
            sprintf(random_type[k++], "%s %d", type[i], j);
    for(k=0; k<WORDS*NUMBERS; k++)
            printf ("%s\n", random_type[k]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What i actually need is to add this information in total of 200 results in an array so that i can transfer it to a struct.

Comment: @falsobuio the second part of my answer creates in total 200 results in an array, I didn't print them due to size.

Comment: @falsobuio I added a third part that creates one string array of 200 strings.